# Weird unicode issue

Tags: python, unicode

I've got following problem. If I'll run my app in eclipse it works OK, but when I'll run it in standalone debuger - I got following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0144' in position 7: ordinal not in range(128)

How can I fix it?

My code fragment:

```
x = x.replace("Ł", "L")
```

Comment: Precede your fragment with `print type(x), repr(x)`; tell us the results

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess, based on (insufficient) information provided:

You are running Python 2.x.

[Guess] `x` is a `str` object.

[Guess] Eclipse sets the default encoding to UTF-8.

The "standard debugger" sets the default encoding to ascii.

Result: splat.

Solution (standard operating procedure for working with Unicode):

- On input, convert all `str` objects to `unicode'.
- Work in Unicode.
- On output, encode all `unicode` objects using whatever encoding the
  consumer of the output is expecting.

**Important update** Actually if `x` was a UTF-8-encoded `str` object, you should have got a message like `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 7: etc etc`.

Note that your actual error message says `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u0144' in position 7: etc etc` This indicates that whatever it is complaining about is (a) a `unicode` object (b) at least 8 characters long. However you are saying in effect that `x` is not a `unicode` object (otherwise x.decode('utf8') would fail) and the other two args of `replace` are only 1 character long. Consequently we have an impossibility.

To help resolve this:

```
print type(x), repr(x) # for Python 2.x
Lstroke = "Ł"
print type(Lstroke), repr(Lstroke)
y = x.replace(Lstroke, 'L')
```

and edit your question to show the actual code that you ran plus the full error message *and the traceback*.

By the way: u'\u0144' is LATIN SMALL LETTER N WITH ACUTE; does that info help at all?

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` to the top of the file to make the Python interpreter aware of which encoding the file uses, in my example UTF-8. You can also do this by saving the file with a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) header. Not sure how Eclipse hints about the encoding but maybe they use `sys.setdefaultencoding()` somehow?.

You can read more details in the Python manual about [source code encoding](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding).

Comment: got encoding in 1st line, the code in eclipse and python debuger is the same

Comment: You have to make sure that the `coding:` line matches the actual encoding in which the editor saves the file. Or better yet, replace that non-ascii character with `"\x??"` where ?? is the hex char code in the encoding of your `x` variable.